# How do DC motor parameters scale with motor size?

Tags: electrical-engineering, motors

Consider the following DC motor parameters:

- Rotor resistance, $R\ [\Omega]$
- Motor constant, $k_t\ [\mathrm{V/rpm}]$
- Inertia, $I\ [\mathrm{kg\cdot m^2]}$

How do they scale with motor size? Do $R$ and $k_t$ depend on $I$?

Comment: There are no answers to this as there are considerably more factors to consider in specifying a motor than those listed here.

Answer (score 1):

Your described motor constant = peak voltage / rotational speed under no load. The latter decreases if your motor resistance increases. Inertia is obviously going to increase with a thicker shaft.